# Elasticsearch character alternative like i or ı

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with some turkish character and need like alternative character to fix it.

```
Example : "İzmir" of our city but some user searching it "ızmır" some Of "Izmır" and sometimes "izmir" .
```

How can I act like i or "ı" or "İ" or "ı " "I" or "i" whenever user using this chars?

[image: results image with "i"]

[image: result image with "ı"]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to correct your mapping from english to Turkish, if you done so can you  paste here your mapping.
Because mapping holds the power to search.

Answer (score 0):

The Turkish analyzer doesn't do that out of the box for you. Example:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "turkish",
  "text": "ızmır Izmır izmir"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "ızmır",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ızmır",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "izmir",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

But you could use [ASCII folding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html) for that purpose — creating an index with a custom analyzer and testing the example against it:

```
PUT /asciifold_example
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
GET asciifold_example/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "ızmır Izmır izmir"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "izmir",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "izmir",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "izmir",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```